# Why the negative form in すぐ行かないと?

Tags: negation

I know that you can use the negative form to ask questions but why is it used in this sentence? I believe this sentence translates to "I have to go right away", but it's literally "I won't go right away"?

Comment: [The 「と」 conditional is also used by itself to imply 「だめ／いけない／ならない」.](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/must)

Comment: Oh, I thought it was just a short for と思う, etc.

Comment: @JimmyYang Do you want to answer the question so I can accept it? Otherwise I'll just self-answer.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not interested. Good luck with self-answering!

Comment: It's short for 行かないとならない as Jimmy said. Example sentence. If I didn't go, something bad would happen.  行かないと悪い事が起こる